# How to avoid blueimp gallery modal opening when click slick slider arrows and dots

Tags: html, gallery, blueimp, slick.js

I am using slick slider and blueimp gallery plugin together for slide and gallery view. So that when i am click slider arrow it open gallery view instead of slide next image.

[image]